# Sprite-Kit animations — using SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to apply `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest` to all the frames in my animation.

Previously, when I was using a non-animated sprite, the following worked:

```swift
super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: playerSize)
self.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest;
```

Now I've added animation frames (see full code below), this doesn't work — the sprite is blurry. I can't work out how to add this filtering mode to all frames.

```swift
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    
    private var playerAtlas: SKTextureAtlas {
        return SKTextureAtlas(named: "Player")
    }
    
    private var playerRunTextures: [SKTexture] {
        return [
            playerAtlas.textureNamed("run1"),
            playerAtlas.textureNamed("run2"),
            playerAtlas.textureNamed("run3"),
            playerAtlas.textureNamed("run4")
        ]
    }
    
    func startRunAnimation() {
        let runAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: playerRunTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(runAnimation), withKey: "playerRunAnimation")
    }
    
    
    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
        let playerSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 50)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: playerSize)
        self.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest;
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
        self.startRunAnimation()
    }

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `SKTextureFilteringMode` for each texture when you create the sprite animation array:

```
private var playerRunTextures: [SKTexture] {
    let spritesheet = [
        "run1",
        "run2",
        "run3",
        "run4"
    ]
    
    return spritesheet.map { name in
        let t1 = playerAtlas.textureNamed(name)
        t1.filteringMode = .nearest //<--- for each texture in the atlas
        return t1
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'SKTexture' to expected argument type 'String'" ?

Comment: which line gives that error?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but I've just tried it again today with fresh eyes and it works perfectly, thank you